# Changing caption to vertical order with subfloat

Tags: graphics, positioning, subfloats

I have 6 figures that I want in a panel of 3 columns and 2 rows. Subfloats can be used to make that panel. However, I also want labels to be set vertically, so a) c) e) and b) d) f) for each row, instead of a) b) c) and d) e) f).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subfloat[]{}\includegraphics[width=25mm]{image1.png}
\subfloat[]{}\includegraphics[width=25mm]{image2.png}
\subfloat[]{}\includegraphics[width=25mm]{image3.png}

\subfloat[]{}\includegraphics[width=25mm]{image4.png}
\subfloat[]{}\includegraphics[width=25mm]{image5.png}
\subfloat[]{}\includegraphics[width=25mm]{image6.png}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Any idea how that can be done without turning to a subfigure environment?

The reason I don't want to turn to a subfigure environment is that `\usepackage{subfig}` isn't compatible with `\usepackage{subcaption}`, and other figures are using `\subfloat` in the document.

Comment: Are all the figures (after `width=65mm`) the same size (vertically)?

Comment: Yes, they are the same size vertically.

Comment: Can you include what we refer to as a minimal working example rather than just a code snippet? Something that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. It allows us to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing and helps us see what document class/packages you're using.

Comment: Yes, sorry Werner, I thought the code snippet was enough in this case. Thanks for the politeness. I've updated the body of text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easiest to just set each vertical stack inside a `minipage` (of fixed width) and set a number of these `minipage`s next to one another. The `\subfloat` numbering will follow the layout within the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}% Just something on the page
\begin{figure}[t]
  \subfloat[]{}\includegraphics[width=25mm]{example-image-a}
  \subfloat[]{}\includegraphics[width=25mm]{example-image-b}
  \subfloat[]{}\includegraphics[width=25mm]{example-image-c}

  \subfloat[]{}\includegraphics[width=25mm]{example-image-c}
  \subfloat[]{}\includegraphics[width=25mm]{example-image-b}
  \subfloat[]{}\includegraphics[width=25mm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \begin{minipage}{25mm}
    \subfloat[]{}\includegraphics[width=25mm]{example-image-a}\par
    \subfloat[]{}\includegraphics[width=25mm]{example-image-b}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{25mm}
    \subfloat[]{}\includegraphics[width=25mm]{example-image-c}\par
    \subfloat[]{}\includegraphics[width=25mm]{example-image-c}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{25mm}
    \subfloat[]{}\includegraphics[width=25mm]{example-image-b}\par
    \subfloat[]{}\includegraphics[width=25mm]{example-image-a}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Werner. What's the role of \par here?

Comment: @jpugliese: It's similar to a `\par`agraph break, or a blank line, and inserts a vertical disposition between elements.